# jquery.backstretch.min.js pulling image from database or variable

Tags: php, javascript

I want to use jquery.backstretch.min.js to resize image variable from database, but it's not working?

**PHP**

```
$usr = $_SESSION['user'];
$q10 = "SELECT * FROM `users`  WHERE `user` = '$usr'";
$result10 = @mysql_query ($q10);
$row10 = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result10);
$avatar = $row10['avatar'];

$myimg = "<img src=\"$avatar\">";
```

**Javascript**

```
$.backstretch("<?php echo $myimg ?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

*(I am assuming that this is the plugin you're talking about: https://github.com/srobbin/jquery-backstretch.)*

You are currently supplying an **image tag** to the plugin initialization, but according to the documentation an **image path** is required. Given that your path is correct and your SQL query does what it’s supposed to, I'd assume that this should solve your problem:

```
$.backstretch("<?php echo $avatar ?>");
```

Comment: Brilliant i tried everything all possibilities how i couldn't think of of it  , happy new year !

Comment: Happy new year and good to hear that it helped. Please consider marking my answers as `accepted` if it solves your problem.